# Can you replace just the lever of this deadbolt latch?

Tags: deadbolt

Can you replace just the lever of this model?

[image]

Comment: Care to tell us what brand it is?

Comment: Kwikset I think -

Comment: Kwikset hardware is rather inexpensive. You'd probably end up paying as much for the lever as for the whole deadbolt kit. Just pick one up and swap the part.

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you know what's expected of you when you ask a question.

Comment: if you buy a new deadbolt at the hardware store, bring your current key, many places will re-key the new kit to your old key while you wait.

Answer (score 2):

Since your lock has a set screw, then yes, you can replace it. The set screw is used to hold the current lever in place. You would simply need another lever that fits that type of deadbolt.

The catch here will be finding another part that fits but is **sold separate** from a deadbolt itself. A quick search turned up no sites selling just that one part.